# How to check multiple versions for deployement

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

We have java and python packages separately but once I download from artifactory I don't want to down load one more time till versions are change in Environment file. As versions are set in Environments how can i ensure if all these versions are there don,t down load again the python and java packages from artifactory.

```
 package_path_java = "org/jfrog/java_path"
 package_version_java = node["package_version_java"] 
 package_version_java_name = "numbers2"
 package_version_java_SNAPSHOT = "5-SNAPSHOT"
 package_name = "deploy_python"
 package_version = node["deploy_python_version"]
```

Do i need to create any text file to save my previous versions or any other way if only one java is there i could have been told if java version is there dont down load how can i move to file and how can i compare do i need to do ruby block as convergence time

Answer (score 0):

You would follow the usual convergence pattern of "test and repair". Check the local system to see what version (if any) is present, and then compare that to the requested version. If they don't match, you run a deploy. This is the same process used by basically everything in Chef. Check out my post at https://coderanger.net/thinking/ for more details on the model.